# select all from access and place in string

Tags: c#, sql, string, ms-access, select

I'm having trouble selecting all items from my access database. I want to select the data in the entire row and keep it in a string, separating each item by a ";". Below is the code i have that will give me the column i specify, but i want all the data in the row.

```
con.Open();
type= checkBox49.Text;

String str = "Select * from distro where type='" + type + "'";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
   str2 = dr.GetString(1);

}
```

Comment: Well you are just getting the second column there, so loop through fro m 0 to numberofcolumns - 1. If you get them into a list you could use String.Join to get the delimiters in. Lots of ways to do this if you look.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like  this  where `columnsCount` is the number of your columns  in  your database table

```
if (dr.Read())
            {
              for (int i = 0; i <columnsCount; i++)
                {
                       str2 +=  string.Join(";",sdr.GetString(i)); 
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select each field by name and combine them together like

```
str2 = dr["FieldName"].ToString() + "." + dr["FieldName"].ToString();
```

Also, I wouldn't reference any fields by number, but by FieldName.

Answer (score 0):

So one approach, with the current code, would be this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (dr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0) { sb.Append(";"); }
        sb.Append(dr.GetString(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: dr.GetString(1) => dr.GetString(i) no ?

Comment: @michael perronoud Dont mind my lack of experience, which item would i refer to as my string? Once i get my data i want to put it into a mailItem.To = string?

Comment: @user3041160, yes; my apologies on that!

Comment: @hexc, you would do something like this `mailItem.To = sb.ToString();` but that also means you'll want to remove the `sb.AppendLine();` if it's for a list of mail recipients.

Answer (score 0):

You could just [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) all the values together.

```
con.Open();
type = checkBox49.Text;

String str = "Select * from distro where type=?";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(type);
using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        var values = new object[dr.FieldCount];
        dr.GetValues(values);
        str2 = string.Join(";", values.Skip(1).Select(d => d.ToString());
    }
}
```

Notice the use of a [parameter in the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too. Standard way to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: this works great! One minor thing, how can i have it skip the first column, column 0, and only give me the data after that? thank yoU!

Comment: I've updated the answer with .Skip() to demonstrate how to skip the first value.

Answer (score 0):

A more global code if all your columns are not string type :

```
        var con = new OleDbConnection();
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);

        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var res = string.Empty;

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            object[] t = new Object[dr.FieldCount];
            if (dr.GetValues(t)>0)
            {
                 res = String.Join(";", (from el in t select el as string).Where(x => x!=null).ToArray());
            }
        }
        return res;
```